# How to persist objects with events in session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, signalr

Currently I am using SignalR to provide chat feature in our application. But I am using Openfire XMPP server as the chat backend. So the SignalR hub creates an XMPP connection in the OnConnected event; this connection is closed in the OnDisconnected event.

More importantly the XMPP connection exposes a few events such as OnAuthenticated, OnRosterStart, OnRosterEnd, OnMessage etc. The hub handles these events and calls the appropriate client-side JS methods.

This is not a single-page-application and therefore the user will navigate between pages; so it is not a great idea to recreate XMPP connections for each page. Also we have edge cases where users lose messages, if the sender sent a message when SignalR connection was terminated and not yet initialized in the new page the recipient landed to!

So I want to manage the XMPP connection lifecycle at a session level; i.e., create the XMPP connection in Session_Start/login; dispose the connection in Session_End/logout. This part is pretty simple; but the tricky part is how do you store the XMPP connection in session and have it reliably fire the events when we have multiple web-servers behind a load balancer.

The way I understand any of the persistence mechanisms ASP.NET provides such as session, cache, application variables etc are all about serializing/deserializing data. But in this case the object I want to store has events that need to be handled.

So the main question is, is there a solution for this at all?

Thanks

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly then SignalR is being used as a bridge to the XMPP. I think you're going to want to store the session key as a cookie or localStorage and have the server keep the XMPP session alive (the client can lookup the connection from the server). When the user times out or disconnects then the server can handle the cleanup. You'll need some kind of backplane for SignalR to let all the servers share the connections.

Comment: @Romoku, it is the "backplane for SignalR" part that has me confused. Any pointers in that direction would be good. Thanks.